# Only allow access to an object's members, not the object itself

Tags: c++, wrapper, encapsulation, forwarding

Given the following class:

```
class Foo
{
public:

    //...

private:

    Bar mBar;
};
```

Is it possible to expose the `mBar` member in such a way that it's members can be accessed, but not the `mBar` object itself?

The reason is that users should be able to access all of `mBar`'s members but they should not be able to assign another `Bar` instance to `mBar`.
`Bar` has a lot of members and it would be cumbersome to write getters/setters and forwarding fuctions for them all. But if `mBar` is made public one is able to do `aFoo.mBar = Bar(/*...*/);`which is the only thing that should not be allowed. 
Deleting `Bar`'s assignment operators is not an option.

Comment: Is inheriting from `Bar` an option (in your specific design plan)?

Comment: Do you want the members of `mBar` to be modifiable by external users?

Comment: Provide getter `const Bar& getBar() const { return mBar;}`?

Comment: _aFoo.mBar = Bar(/*...*/); ... is the only thing that should not be allowed_ - But assigning `mBar` members new values shoud be allowed?

Comment: I don't understand.  Do you want the outside to gain `const` access to `mBar`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo @Jarod42 @L.F. @Holt The outside should have full access (not only const) to `mBar`'s members. `Bar`'s constructor allows for different configurations, but only one of those is valid in the context of `Foo`. `Foo` makes sure it's `mBar` member is created with a valid configuration, after that the outside can have full access to `mBar`'s members but should not be able to replace the `Bar` instance with another one.

Comment: Is the design sound? Can you replace the theoretical `Foo`s and `Bar`s with names that could help visualize what you're trying to accomplish? One idea: Wrap the `Bar` in a non-copyable/movable container and expose it like @Jarod42 suggested, only non-const.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `Foo` is a `Document`. `Bar` is one of the components of a `Document` that has no connection to any of the other components that form a `Document` except for the fact that all components of a `Document` have to be constructed with the same configuration settings. `Bar's` interface is sufficiently encapsulated that it can be exposed directly but it should not be possible to assign another `Bar` instance (that was possibly created with a different configuration).

Comment: Ok, then the non-copyable/movable container approach in @Jarod42's answer should do fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you only want to protect against errors and not Machiavelli, `operator->` might help (you might probably want a wrapper instead of directly put it in foo though):

```
class Foo
{
public:
    //...
    const Bar* operator ->() const { return &mBar; }
    Bar* operator ->() { return &mBar; }
private:
    Bar mBar;
};
```

so

```
Foo foo;

foo->bar_member;
foo.foo_member;

// Machiavelli
*foo.operator->() = Bar();
```

Comment: Imho the main reason for encapsulation is to guard against errors, not malintent, so this looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably rethink your design but here is a possible indirect way using an intermediate `get` method:

```
struct Bar {
    int intAttr;
};

class Foo {
    Bar mBar;

public:

    template <class U>
    U& get(U Bar::* p) {
        return mBar.*p;
    }
};
```

This way, you can access any public member of `mBar` using:

```
Foo foo;
foo.get(&Bar::intAttr);      // get
foo.get(&Bar::intAttr) = 0;  // set
```

Comment: Can even use variadic, and `std::invoke` to allow member-methods and member non-methods

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, but you'd have to be careful against, as you call it, *Machiavelli*, because you could use `operator=` to set `mBar` itself ;)

Comment: Indeed. and it is not really a hack (whereas mine is IMO). a simple `static_assert` might solve it pretty easily though.

Comment: @Holt "Rethink the design" - Is it that unheard of that `Bar`'s own interface is sufficiently encapsulated that it can be exposed directly but the only invariant `Foo` has to protect is on how it's `Bar` is constructed? (`Bar` is a fully fledged class btw, not a simple struct).

Comment: @Unimportant I don't say that this is impossible, but this looks fishy at best. Starting with the fact that you have a class `Bar` that seems to have a different behavior depending on how you construct it... If `Bar` was immutable, then I would perfectly understood that you may have different constructors that would set a `Bar` instance in a different state, and then you only want to allow one of these constructs for `Foo`, but in this case, accessing `mBar` by `const&` would be sufficient. This does not seem to be the case here, so the design of `Bar` does not seem sound to me.

Comment: @Holt: I might imagine cases like internal counter (for metrics). with a copy which also copy the metric and Foo which would not allow this "reset".